# Animate image from thumbnail to full screen size image in Grid View

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I need to achieve the effect of scaling an image from a thumbnail to full size on the entire screen. It's important that the animation starts from the position corresponding to a specific thumbnail in grid view. I would like to achieve an effect like this: https://streamable.com/gj1vef.

The closest I've come to achieving this effect was by using the animations package (https://pub.dev/packages/animations) and this code

```
return OpenContainer(
                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                          closedShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0)),
                          transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                          openBuilder: (context, action) {
                            return Scaffold(
                              body: Center(
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    context.router.pop();
                                  },
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    _entityKeys[entity.id]!,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          closedBuilder: (context, action) {
                            return Image.asset(_entityKeys[entity.id]!,
                                width: 114, height: 114, fit: BoxFit.cover);
                          },
                        );
```

but in the recording https://streamable.com/o9rzf0, there is noticeable jumping between images, and it's not the effect I'm satisfied with. Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve such an effect?

Comment: You can make this with Hero widget. just wrap your image with Hero() and give it a tag. Then put the same widget to another window.